# I cannot use numpy.zeros function 'TypeError: 'list' object is not callable'

Tags: python, list, numpy, typeerror, numpy-ndarray

I cannot use the NumPy.zeros function, it's the first time I come across this problem and I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I checked other questions about the same problem but seemed that those people accidentally assigned a function to the built-in function 'list', that doesn't seem to be the issue I'm having:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[4,5,9,6], [9,1,5,7], [1,5,7,3], [6, 9, 5, 2], [9,8,2,5]])
N, D = X.shape
```

Now I try to create a zero vector with as many rows as D:

```
np.zeros((D,))
```

and I receive this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-ffee5417280b> in <module>
----> 1 np.zeros((D,1))

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

What's exactly wrong with my code?

Comment: You should do `np.array((D,1))` which is different from your code snippet but matches your traceback output. I have tried to execute all the code you have provided, no problems occurred. Can you provide actual code that you try to run?

Comment: Confirm cannot reproduce on my end.

Comment: Look for something that says `np.zeros = [...]` or `fn( . . ., out = np.zeros)` somewhere in your code, looks like the function got overwritten somewhere.

Comment: Basically, search your code for `np.zeros` not followed by a `(`.  Or if you're in an IDE, `print(np.zeros)` and make sure it's still a function

Comment: Yes, I accidentally assigned the np.zeros function to a list, and hence the problem, fixed.

Comment: @JMarcos87 Please consider deleting the question as it might be misguiding for people with actual error: `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: Don't delete, it's still a common issue.  I will closevote though, since it's more of a typo issue (albeit a frustratingly common one).

Answer (score 0):

I run your code on python 3.7, that is correct.

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[4,5,9,6], [9,1,5,7], [1,5,7,3], [6, 9, 5, 2], [9,8,2,5]])
N, D = X.shape
print(np.zeros((D,)))
```

output is:

```
[0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

check the spaces in your code.